# issue retrieving services from manifest

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to retrieve the service that a specific app require. i write this code

```
        pm = context.getPackageManager();

        try {
            pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
            requireService = pkgInfo.services;

            if(requireService != null) {
            for(int i=0; i<requireService.length; i++) {
                services = requireService[i];

            }
            mytextview.setText(services.toString());
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        }
```

When i execute this code i get the service but in this way: "ServiceInfo{422c12b8 com.package.name.serviceName}"

what is it "ServiceInfo{422c12b8" and how can i remove this? another bug is that i show only one service also if the app have more than one service required.

Comment: "ServiceInfo{422c12b8" is just the standard behaviour of toString on Java objects.  It just gives the object's class and identity hash code.

Comment: And then how do I remove it?

Comment: And you only see one service because your set services to each listed service in turn.  After exiting the for loop the value of services will be be the last service encountered.

Comment: To change the text you will need to not call the toString metbod.  What do you want the text to be?

Comment: I just want to write that the services required in the TextView.

Comment: Sure.  But the ServiceInfo instances you are finding do not have a sensible toString implementation so using that is not very useful.  Perhaps calling services.loadLabel(pm) will be more useful?